# How to extract data from a JSON field store in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this JSON in a bigquery table

```
{"a":"b","superParams": {"isTest": "false"}}
```

And I would like to select superParas inner JSON

When I run this
`select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR('{"a":"b",superParams":{"isTest":"false"}}','$.a')`

I get 
`a`

When I run this
`select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR('{"a":"b",superParams":{"isTest":"false"}}','$.superParams')`

I get 
`null` 
Instead of `{"isTest":"false"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `superParams` is an object, not a scalar, so you need to use the `JSON_EXTRACT` function instead. Try this:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"a":"b","superParams":{"isTest":"false"}}','$.superParams')
```

Comment: Thanks to @dsesto for pointing out that `superParams` was missing the quote on the left in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

In case if your intention was to actually extract value for example of isTest parameter - use below

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR('{"a":"b","superParams":{"isTest":"false"}}','$.superParams.isTest')
```